# MkDocs - Have a file use a specific template

Tags: templates, jinja2, markdown, mkdocs

I’m probably not understanding something fundamental to Jinja and/or MkDocs but hopefully someone can point me in the right direction. I’m building a static website and using MkDocs. I need to have a landing page, some documentation pages and some product pages. Each of these will use different templates that extend `main.html` in different ways.

What I don’t understand is how to ensure that when building my pages, MkDocs knows which of my templates, say `landing.html`, `product.html` or `docs.html` template to use for a given markdown file, say `landing.md`, `product1.md`, `product2.md`, `product3.md` And `doc1.md`, `doc2.md` and `doc3.md`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is to use the `template` key which is documented at https://www.mkdocs.org/user-guide/writing-your-docs/#meta-data